# how to apply if condition in C#

Tags: c#

```
if (excellInfoUpdateL3.canSendLetter == "N/A") {
  return ClosureInfo.canClose ="N";
}
else {
  return ClosureInfo.canClose = excellInfoUpdateL3.canSendLetter;
}
```

can above code be written in a single line using if condition or something like that?

Comment: huh ? you need to edit your answer, its unreadable in this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in one line like this:

```
return excellInfoUpdateL3.canSendLetter == "N/A" ? "N" : excellInfoUpdateL3.canSendLetter;
```

Comment: Or, slightly better, this `return returnClosureInfo.canClose = excellInfoUpdateL3.canSendLetter == "N/A" ?  "N" : excellInfoUpdateL3.canSendLetter;`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can by using ternary operator

```
return (excellInfoUpdateL3.canSendLetter == "N/A")?"N":excellInfoUpdateL3.canSendLetter;
```

Here is how ternary operator works

```
(Condition)?if contion is true : if condition is false
```